# Connecting the A and M components of the MEAN stack - tips and guidance needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, svg

I have an internship project that requires me to use the MEAN stack to develop a simple application, I'll try to explain briefly what I did and what I need help with.

[image: Start page]

This will be the start page for my application.

There will be two interested parties using the application.

One of them lets us call it the creator, see a screen similar to the image above, introduce a specific number on the input box, and generate a matrix like the above one. Only the creator can see this screen.

After the matrix is created, the creator will be able to send an email to a pre-defined list of users containing a link to a page where the users (the second interested party using the application) will be able to add content to each one of the cells of the matrix above. Then, once all the cells have content on them, the users will press a "Submit" button which should save and store the filled matrix into a MongoDB database from where I can query the results of and perform some statistical analysis.

I have two (three) issues now:

1) I first developed this matrix using only HTML+Javascript using SVG figures because it was simple and more intuitive to me;

2) I then tried to convert the HTML+Javascript version to AngularJS for two reasons:

2.1 - I thought it would be easy to integrate it with MongoDB if I was already using a component of the MEAN stack;

2.2 - The matrix could be stored in JSON or more precisely, I could add a series of `JSON.parse("string that represents a line of the matrix")` strings into a matrix instead of just appending SVG string into a single huge SVG picture;

3) In AngularJS (maybe I'm doing something very wrong) I cant get the desired behavior as some things don't work (namely, inside an if/else statement some of the branches dont work), I'll show the code below soon.

After all this explanation, my questions are simply two:

First:

What am I doing wrong in the below code?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var RectangleDim=30;

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.graph = {'width': 5000, 'height': 5000};

    $scope.circles = [

      /*  JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 20, \"r\":15}"),

        {"x": 20, "y": 60, "r":20},

        {"x": 18, "y": 10, "r":40} */
    ];

        $scope.draw=function(val)
        {
           // val = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;
            return JSON.parse('{\"cx\":'+val+', "cy": 20, "r":30}');
           // $scope.circles.push(JSON.parse('{\"x\":'+val+', "y": 220, "r":30}'));
        };

    $scope.rectangles = [

       //     {'x':220,  'y':220,  'width' : 300, 'height' : 100},
       // {'x':520,  'y':220,  'width' : 10, 'height' : 10},
    ];

        $scope.DrawRect=function(xpos,ypos) {
           return JSON.parse('{\"x\":' + xpos + ', \"y\":' + ypos + ', \"width\":' + RectangleDim + ', \"height\":' + RectangleDim+ ', \"style\":\"fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\"'+ '}');
        };


        $scope.Debug=function(desiredNo){
            desiredNo=document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;
            for(var i = 0;i < RectangleDim*desiredNo+desiredNo;i++){
                $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(i+RectangleDim+1,40));
            }
        };

        $scope.DrawLineOdd=function(desiredNo,lineNo,pozY){
            var pozX = lineNo*RectangleDim;
            var aux = 2*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-1-2*lineNo;
            for (var j = 0; j < aux; j++) {
                $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozX, pozY));//$scope.DrawRect(pozX, pozY);
                pozX += RectangleDim;
            }
            //return aux;
        };

        $scope.DrawMatrixPerfectProgression=function(desiredNo) {

            desiredNo=document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;


            var line=0;
            var pozy=0;
            while(line<Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))) {
                $scope.DrawLineOdd(desiredNo, line, pozy);
                //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
                line += 1;
                pozy+=RectangleDim;
            }
            //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
        };

        $scope.DrawLineEven=function(desiredNo, lineNo, pozY){
            var pozX = lineNo*RectangleDim;
            //var pozY = lineno*20;
            var aux = 2*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-2*lineNo;
            for (var j = 0; j < aux; j++) {
                $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozX, pozY));
                pozX += RectangleDim;
            }
            //return aux;
        };

        $scope.DrawMatrixEvenProgression=function(desiredNo) {

            desiredNo=document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;

            var line=0;
            var pozy=0;
            while(line<Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)) {
                $scope.DrawLineEven(desiredNo, line, pozy);
                //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
                line += 1;
                pozy+=RectangleDim;
            }
            //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
        };

    $scope.AddExtraRectangles=function(desiredNo) {
        desiredNo = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;

        var arg1 = desiredNo - (  Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo)));
        var arg2 = desiredNo-(Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)*Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2))-Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2);
        var OptimalLeftOver = Math.min( arg1  ,arg2 );
        //We add two rectangles per row: one at the beginning one at the end
        //we start with the row below the first one

        var line;
        var pozy;
        var pozx1, pozx2;
        var nRectLine_i;

        if(OptimalLeftOver===arg1){
            line=1;//1st line is skipped
            pozy=RectangleDim;
            pozx1 = 0;
            while(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                nRectLine_i = 2* Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-1-2*line;
                pozx2 = (line-1)*RectangleDim+RectangleDim*(nRectLine_i+1);//pozx1+nRectLine_i+2*RectangleDim;
                $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozx1,pozy));
                OptimalLeftOver-=1;
                if(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                    $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozx2, pozy));
                    OptimalLeftOver -= 1;
                }
                //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
                line += 1;
                pozy+=RectangleDim;
                pozx1=RectangleDim*line - RectangleDim;
            }
            //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
        }
        else {
            line=1;//1st line is skipped
            pozy=RectangleDim;
            pozx1 = 0;
            while(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                nRectLine_i = 2* Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-2*line;
                pozx2 = RectangleDim*(line-1)+RectangleDim*(nRectLine_i+1);//pozx1+nRectLine_i+2*RectangleDim;
                $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozx1,pozy));
                OptimalLeftOver-=1;
                if(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                    $scope.rectangles.push($scope.DrawRect(pozx2, pozy));
                    OptimalLeftOver -= 1;
                }
                //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
                line += 1;
                pozy+=RectangleDim;
                pozx1=RectangleDim*line - RectangleDim;
            }
            //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
        }
    };

        $scope.DrawMatrix=function(desiredNo)
        {
            /* Chooses optimal leftover number based on the progression formulas.
             Attempts to minimize the work of the designer of the response form without
             making too much assumptions */
            desiredNo = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;

            var arg1 = desiredNo - (  Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo)));
            var arg2 = desiredNo - (Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)*Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2))-Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2);
            var OptimalLeftOver = Math.min( arg1  ,arg2 );
            //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = 'There are '+OptimalLeftOver+' questions missing!'+ arg1+ '___'+arg2;
            //console.log(arg1);
            if(OptimalLeftOver===arg1){
                desiredNo = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;

                $scope.DrawMatrixPerfectProgression(desiredNo);
                $scope.AddExtraRectangles(desiredNo);
            }
            else {
                desiredNo = document.getElementById("NumQuest").value;

                $scope.DrawMatrixEvenProgression(desiredNo);
                $scope.AddExtraRectangles(desiredNo);
            }
        };
}
);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ["app"]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


</head>


<div id="body">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Num questões:</label>
    <input Id="NumQuest" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="Num questões..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1"
           />
    <p><button ng-click="DrawMatrixPerfectProgression(NumQuest)">Draw</button></p>

    <svg ng-attr-height="{{graph.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{graph.width}}">

    <circle ng-repeat="circle in circles"

            ng-attr-cx="{{circle.cx}}"

            ng-attr-cy="{{circle.cy}}"

            ng-attr-r="{{circle.r}}">
    </circle>

     <rect ng-repeat="rect in rectangles"

           ng-attr-x="{{rect.x}}"

           ng-attr-y="{{rect.y}}"

           ng-attr-width="{{rect.width}}"

           ng-attr-height="{{rect.height}}"

          ng-attr-style="{{rect.style}}"
            >

     </rect>

     </svg>
</div>
    </div>
   <!-- <svg ng-attr-height="{{graph.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{graph.width}}">


</svg> -->


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/{{JQUERY_VERSION}}/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-{{JQUERY_VERSION}}.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second question(s):

Is there a decent way to improve this in order to make it easier for me to add MongoDB into this small project?

And secondly, I'm devising all the code using the IDE WebStorm 10. If I need support for MongoDB/Node.JS and all the other server-side code dependencies, should I add more JS source files under a normal project tree? Or create separated files?

As you can see I'm still new to web design and web projects but, I'm eager to learn!

Reference:

Old JS code using only the SVG+ Inner.HTML approach:

```
/* Handle all the cases specifically:
    Perfect square number
    Ending with two squares - N² + N
    Missing a number of squares equal to the number of squares of a given line
    Other cases
 */

var beginSVG = '<svg width=\"3072\" height=\"3720\">';
//var endSVG = '</svg>';
var finalTable = beginSVG;
var RectangleDim=30;

function GetRectangle(xOffset, yOffset) {
    var beginRect = '<rect';
    var xOffSet =  ' x=\"'+xOffset+'\"';
    var yOffSet =  ' y=\"'+yOffset+'\"';
    var dim = 'width=\"'+RectangleDim+'\" \height=\"'+RectangleDim+'\" ';
    var style = ' style=\"fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\" /> \' ';
    return beginRect+xOffSet+yOffSet+dim+style;
}

//This is to be used with the function DrawRectangleToAdd which specifies the rectangles that are to be added to fullfill the entire questionnaire
function GetRectangleToAdd(xOffset, yOffset) {
    var beginRect = '<rect';
    var xOffSet =  ' x=\"'+xOffset+'\"';
    var yOffSet =  ' y=\"'+yOffset+'\"';
    var dim = 'width=\"'+RectangleDim+'\" \height=\"'+RectangleDim+'\" ';
    var style = ' style=\"fill:rgb(25,2,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(1,0,0)\" /> \' ';
    return beginRect+xOffSet+yOffSet+dim+style;
}

function DrawMatrixClear() {
    finalTable=beginSVG;
    document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
    }


function DrawRect(xpos,ypos){
    finalTable += GetRectangle(xpos,ypos);
}

//To be used with an array that specifies the positions of the rectangles to add
function DrawRectangleToAdd(xpos,ypos){
    finalTable += GetRectangleToAdd(xpos,ypos);
}

//line 0 is the largest line
function DrawLineOdd(desiredNo, lineno, pozY){
   // var lineTab=beginSVG;
    var i = lineno;
    var pozX = i*RectangleDim;
    //var pozY = lineno*20;
    var aux = 2*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-1-2*i;
    for (var j = 0; j < aux; j++) {
        DrawRect(pozX, pozY);
        pozX += RectangleDim;
    }
    return aux;
}

function DrawMatrixPerfectProgression(desiredNo) {
    var line=0;
    var pozy=0;
    while(line<Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))) {
        var teste = DrawLineOdd(desiredNo, line, pozy);
        //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
        line += 1;
        pozy+=RectangleDim;
    }
    document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
}

function DrawLineEven(desiredNo, lineno, pozY){
    // var lineTab=beginSVG;
    var i = lineno;
    var pozX = i*RectangleDim;
    //var pozY = lineno*20;
    var aux = 2*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-2*i;
    for (var j = 0; j < aux; j++) {
        DrawRect(pozX, pozY);
        pozX += RectangleDim;
    }
    return aux;
}

function DrawMatrixEvenProgression(desiredNo) {
    var line=0;
    var pozy=0;
    while(line<Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)) {
        var teste = DrawLineEven(desiredNo, line, pozy);
        //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
        line += 1;
        pozy+=RectangleDim;
    }
    document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
}

function AddExtraRectangles(desiredNo) {
    var arg1 = desiredNo - (  Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo)));
    var arg2 = desiredNo-(Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)*Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2))-Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2);
    var OptimalLeftOver = Math.min( arg1  ,arg2 );
    //We add two rectangles per row: one at the beginning one at the end
    //we start with the row below the first one

    var line;
    var pozy;
    var pozx1, pozx2;
    var nRectLine_i;

    if(OptimalLeftOver===arg1){
        line=1;//1st line is skipped
        pozy=RectangleDim;
        pozx1 = 0;
        while(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
            nRectLine_i = 2* Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-1-2*line;
            pozx2 = (line-1)*RectangleDim+RectangleDim*(nRectLine_i+1);//pozx1+nRectLine_i+2*RectangleDim;
            DrawRectangleToAdd(pozx1,pozy);
            OptimalLeftOver-=1;
            if(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                DrawRectangleToAdd(pozx2, pozy);
                OptimalLeftOver -= 1;
            }
            //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
            line += 1;
            pozy+=RectangleDim;
            pozx1=RectangleDim*line - RectangleDim;
        }
        //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
    }
    else
    {
        line=1;//1st line is skipped
        pozy=RectangleDim;
        pozx1 = 0;
        while(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
            nRectLine_i = 2* Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))-2*line;
            pozx2 = RectangleDim*(line-1)+RectangleDim*(nRectLine_i+1);//pozx1+nRectLine_i+2*RectangleDim;
            DrawRectangleToAdd(pozx1,pozy);
            OptimalLeftOver-=1;
            if(OptimalLeftOver>0) {
                DrawRectangleToAdd(pozx2, pozy);
                OptimalLeftOver -= 1;
            }
            //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = teste;
            line += 1;
            pozy+=RectangleDim;
            pozx1=RectangleDim*line - RectangleDim;
        }
        //document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = finalTable;
    }
}

function DrawMatrix(desiredNo) {
    /* Chooses optimal leftover number based on the progression formulas.
    Attempts to minimize the work of the designer of the response form without
    making too much assumptions
     */
    var arg1 = desiredNo - (  Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(desiredNo)));
    var arg2 = desiredNo - (Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2)*Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2))-Math.floor((Math.sqrt(4*desiredNo+1)-1)/2);
    var OptimalLeftOver = Math.min( arg1  ,arg2 );
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = 'There are '+OptimalLeftOver+' questions missing!'+ arg1+ '___'+arg2;
    console.log(arg1);
    if(OptimalLeftOver===arg1){
        DrawMatrixPerfectProgression(desiredNo);
        AddExtraRectangles(desiredNo);
    }
    else {
        DrawMatrixEvenProgression(desiredNo);
        AddExtraRectangles(desiredNo);
    }
}
```

PS: Yes, I've read this question: [Using AngularJs and MongoDB/Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881161/using-angularjs-and-mongodb-mongoose),

but it didn't really clear my doubts, and I don't think that's what I need.

What I need is to learn how to connect components together inside a /src project folder and the best practices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well typically there is no direct connection through mongo and angular.
It connects through angular node (through angular services talking to express (node based) endpoints) - the callbacks in express invoke mongoose which is a the typical connection between node and mongo.
Download mean.io - look at the articles package and try to trace the callbacks from angular views/controllers/services ( in packages/articles/public/) and how they call the express routes and callbacks in packages/articles/server...
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so, in terms of structure it should be doable with what I already did to connect MongoDB? Is the file structure okay?