# Inserting data into MongoDB using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to insert some user input data to database, instead of mySQL i have decided to use MongoDB. here i have my input form

form.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="formController">

<form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"><br>
    <input class="form-control" name="address" Placeholder="Address">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
</form>

</div>
```

how can i insert these values into MongoDB using angular ?
Note: formController is empty and has no codes in it !

Comment: You need a server of some sort, you cannot write to a database directly from the client.

Comment: Please be more specific!

Comment: Angular is a frontend framework. It doesn't insert into Mongo

Comment: Is it possible to insert without a backend ?

Comment: No. What are you using to host your HTML? Node.js? PHP? You need something like that to insert into Mongo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AngularJs and MongoDB/Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881161/using-angularjs-and-mongodb-mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing MongoDB is not so different than MySQL. You need some sort of library that will help you connect to it (like you would do in all SQL databases that I know). For that you might need a backend to handle the form submission, as @cbass mentioned.

Also take a look at a few restful approaches https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

I don't know any PHP so I cannot help with that. But take a look at this: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

Comment: is this possible to do with PHP ?

Comment: I revised my answer take a look above. Hope it will give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mongo does not have a vanilla http interface you will need a backend adapter such as Mongoose for Node, or ActiveRecord w/prostrgres (Rails)

There are "databases", ElasticSearch comes to mind, that have a Restful JSON interface. ElasticSearch is not what I would consider a System of Record Database, but I am trying to make a point that you need an http/json layer to accept your requests and push the data into a database.

If you know JS well enough definitely give Mongoose/Express/Node a try. For any real application you will want a proper backend and Node is an easy place to start.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the only part I hate about Stackoverflow. People here consider
> that you should know everything before posting question.

Considering that you are new to Angular(like I was once), lets get some points cleared:

1. Angular is a front-end framework, it will manage how data looks in HTML
2. To make your app interact with MongoDB, you need nodejs or any other backend.
3. You need to create a RESTful API. Hitting direct queries on DB is really not a standard for modern web-apps. Checkout this example: https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd
4. When done creating RESTful api, you need to hit that api using GET method in angualar.

   You controller might look like this:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('myapp');
   .controller('lister', ['$http', function($http) {
   var self = this;

   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/testCollection')
     .then(function(response) {

   self.items = response.data;
   }, function(errResponse) {
   console.error('Error while fetching menus' + errResponse);
   });
   }]);
   ```